# Disable Apache autostart

Tags: apache, webserver

I'm on a fresh 10.9 install and the default Apache server is `org.apache.httpd: Already loaded` after each startup. Is there a way to disable that autostart?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

OS X provides `launchctl` to control which daemons are started at boot time.

To stop and disable Apache:

1. Open [Terminal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_%28OS_X%29)
2. Type the following command (type your login password when `sudo` requests it):

   ```
   sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
   ```

**A few words on `launchctl`'s `-w` option**

The `-w` option is the silver bullet for stopping/disabling Apache. It tells `launchctl` to do its job regardless of any configuration settings that would otherwise prevent it from unloading the service, as explained in `man launchctl`:

```
-w       Overrides the Disabled key and sets it to false or true for the load and
         unload subcommands respectively. In previous versions, this option would
         modify the configuration file. Now the state of the Disabled key is stored
         elsewhere on- disk in a location that may not be directly manipulated by any
         process other than launchd.
```

(It turns out that, in OS X Mavericks (10.9), "elsewhere on-disk" is `/private/var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd/overrides.plist`.)

The `-w` option is indispensable if you started Apache with `apachectl start`: as explained [in this Superuser answer](https://superuser.com/questions/455505/how-do-i-start-apache-in-osx-mountain-lion#460313). `apachectl` not only starts Apache but also modifies `/private/var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd/overrides.plist` like this:

```
<key>org.apache.httpd</key>
<dict>
        <key>Disabled</key>
        <false/>
</dict>
```

In this particular case you can also use `apachectl`:

```
sudo apachectl stop
```

to stop Apache and to set `Disabled` to `true`.

Comment: I tried that, but each time I run `sudo apachectl start` the launch daemon seems to be activated again after restart.

Comment: Try with `-w`: `sudo launchctl -w unload ...`. If it doesn't help, could you post the output of `ps -ef|grep httpd|grep -v grep`?

Comment: I tried `-w` before, same result. Here is the output: http://pastebin.com/h14t8fEv

Comment: Thanks, does `sudo launchctl1 ...` return an error message? Could you post the output of `grep apache /var/log/com.apple.launchd/launchd-shutdown.system.log` and `sudo grep apache /var/log/system.log`?

Comment: Yes: `sudo: launchctl1: command not found` and here is the output: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=zxKvYV4i

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo, I meant `sudo launchctl...` and not `sudo launchctl1...`, but I've seen that `launchctl` works as expected, thanks for posting the output. Apache is indeed started by `launchctl` when OS X starts up, the PPID is 1, so "something" re-enables it. Do you have other software, like "OS X Server" (https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/os-x-server/id714547929?mt=12), that requires Apache?

Comment: No, it's a fresh install and the only thing I've got installed that could start Apache is Xcode. I remember reading a while ago that `apachectl start` registers the launch daemon. Maybe the best thing to do is execute `launchctl unload` on shutdown?

Comment: That's the key, `apachectl start` starts Apache and modifies `/private/var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd/overrides.plist` to **enable** it in a similar way `launchctl` does (http://superuser.com/questions/455505/how-do-i-start-apache-in-osx-mountain-lion). Try `apachectl stop`, it should stop **and** disable it for good.

Comment: Great, thanks for your feedback, I edited my answer to add information on `apachectl`. Option `-w` would have worked too (at least it worked for me), unfortunately the command I told you to type (`sudo launchctl -w unload ...`) was wrong, the correct syntax is `sudo launchctl unload -w ...`.